# I want to know about Serial Communication in Nodemcu. How we can use more than 2 serials at a time like we use in arduino

Tags: serial-communication, nodemcu, software-serial

I'm new and I just want to know if we can use more than 2 Serial comms in nodemcu by using Software Serial.. I m currently using 3 modules which need serial communication and I want to use them with a single Nodemcu. Is it possible?

I'm trying to use GPIO 4 and 5 for one serial Comm
and Rxd2 and Txd2 for second serial.
will it work?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work.

Although there are two UARTs(0 and 1) available to NodeMCU, UART 1 is not capable of receiving data and is therefore transmit only.

For reference: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/uart/

Comment: Thanks for replying .. I need to know that how can I use three different Serial comms in a single nodemcu using SoftwareSerial. Is it even possible?

Comment: You can't.  The H/W architecture doesn't support it easily.  One UART back to the mothership, and Wifi to the world.  That's what you get, all in a $2 package.

Comment: What if I use SoftwareSerial?